# Functions of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose that $f : A \to B$ is a function. If $S \subseteq A$, then we define $f(S)$ to be the set $f(S)=\{f(x) \,:\, x\in S\}$.

So for example, if $f : R \to R$ is given by $f(x) = x^2$, 
then we have $f(\{1,2,3\}) = \{1,4,9\}$, we have $f(\{−2, 2, 3\}) = \{4, 9\}$, and $f([−2, 2]) = [0, 4]$.

a) Prove that if $S\subseteq A$ and $T \subseteq A$,then $f(S\cap T)\subseteq f(S)\cap f(T)$.

b) Give an example of an function f :R→R and two sets $S,T \subseteq R$ such that $f(S\cap T) \neq f(S)\cap f(T)$.

Need help, don't have a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a)
$u \in f(S \cap T)$

$\implies u=f(x)$ for some $x \in S \cap T$

$ \implies  u=f(x)$ for some $x \in S$ $ \quad \text{and} \quad $ $   u=f(x)$ for some $x \in T$

$\implies u \in f(S) \cap f(T)$.

b) Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x)=1, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Defining $S= \{1,2\}$ and $T=\{2,3\}$ suffices.